# Prompt in php loop

Tags: php, loops, prompt

I have a php system that connects to a webservice, gets data and based on that data generates txt files... - it all goes automaticly while data ends.

The thing is: customer wants to enter some values himself - say ... everytime one mssql record is read he wants to change id for his own system (there are many records each time system is run).

So basicly he needs a prompt box so easy to create in js.

But is there a way to create any kind of brompt box inside php loop?

Comment: Why not? Obviously you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That prompt will not work while your `PHP` loop is running, and hence it kills the whole purpose of it. Your Prompt will show `x` times back to back if you put in a loop that runs `x` times and it will not return data to your `PHP` loop to update values. Hence this is not doable. You could use `javascript` and `AJAX` to send those values back to your PHP, but not directly from your `PHP` loop can you do that.

By the time `JavaScript` starts working, `PHP` has already gone. You would need to post that Prompt answer from `JavaScript` back to `PHP` to update the values

**Edit**

I just put up a test code for you, to explain it further using your idea. Try it

```
<?php
echo "<script>";

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
   echo "var a=prompt('Please answer this question');";     
/* You wont be getting back this value in PHP from user just like that. And obviously it will kill the user experience. Try it */
}

echo "</script>";

?>
```

Comment: Yep. I was hoping that may be a way around this problem. Unfortunatelly you just can't do everything in php. Thx for your help.